# docker: Error response from daemon: runtime "io.containerd.runc.v2" binary not installed "containerd-shim-runc-v2": file does not exist: unknown

Tags: docker, ubuntu

After docker installation, I tried to run

```
docker run --rm hello-world
```

And get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: runtime "io.containerd.runc.v2" binary not installed "containerd-shim-runc-v2": file does not exist: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure it's not the "right" solution, but I found a workaround on this site:
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3473#issuecomment-516887500

To solve it I did:

```
❯ find / -name containerd-shim-runc-v1
/usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v1
```

And then: (make sure that this is the right path in your machine)

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v1 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2
```